# Connecting event handler to custom UIView component

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a custom UIView component called ControlsDockView and I have a couple of buttons in the view. I know that you can add the click event for the buttons directly to the UIViewController and proceed further. But would it be possible for me to add the event handler to the ControlsDockView? If so, how?

For android, I know we can directly have the event handler written in the view but is it different with swift?

Do I have to go through the view controller for it? Maybe it is a newbie question but I need to know how I can proceed with this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create an action for a button in your custom view. Easiest way is probably to ctrl-drag from interface builder to your view code.

you will then get an `IBAction func actionHandler(sender: UIButton) {}` in your view code.

Another way to set this up is by adding the action to the buttons in your loadFromNib method or constructor in the custom view.

However, be careful about adding any kind of logic that isn't directly related to the view in those actions as it's considered an extremely bad coding practise to add business logic to you views in such a manner.

Comment: I just tried this out and apparently you need to have an inheritance from the ViewController to be able to have an IBAction working on the custom view. The ctrl-drag function would only work then. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No. UIView has no problem handling these. Have you set the custom class in the xib so that xcode knows to map the xib to the actual class?

Comment: Apparently, my approach was wrong. My problem was that I was creating my view directly in the viewcontroller without having anything to do with the xib. That's the wrong thing I was doing. What you explained was right. Thank you very much Moriya

Comment: Also, the idea is to implement some sort of a central event bus that would contain a producer consumer kind of algorithm which is why i need the mechanism to dispatch an event to the global event bus from the view